# jQuery - .prepend() for each element in list of input's?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use `prepend` for each element in a list of `input`'s within a `form`?
The prepend below only prepends the first element - is it possible to prepend the label for all items:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sg1").each(function(){
        $(this).prepend("<label for=\""+$(this).attr("id")+"\">"+$(this).attr("id")+"</label>");
    });
});
</script>
<form id="sg1">
    <input name="member1" id="member1" value="jack" />
    <input name="member2" id="member2" value="carter" />
    <input name="member3" id="member3" value="jackson" />
    <input name="member4" id="member4" value="tielk" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RM5wG/

Comment: updated snippet - it is *such* a pain to enter in tags on stackoverflow... a smart str_replace on `&lt;` would do some good

Comment: Indent the code block four spaces instead of using `<pre><code>`.

Comment: then you'd have to put four spaces in front of each line of the code...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to loop through the inputs instead of the form, and use something like [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) instead, like this:

```
$("#sg1 input").each(function(){
  $('<label for="'+ this.id +'">' + this.id + '</label>').insertBefore(this);
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/UahEh/)

[`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) inserts an element as the first child, but an `<input>` doesn't get children, if you want it before use [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) to place it before the element you pass to [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) :)

Comment: You can also swap and use `.before`, IIRC.

Comment: @strager - Yep that'd work the other way around, ideally you'd do `$('<label />', {for: this.id, id: this.id }).insertBefore(this)` if doing many elements, that's the reasoning for leaving it `.insertBefore()`, in case the OP incorporates his previous question as well :)

Comment: Ah, okay.  But your comment says `id: this.id`, which looks wrong.  (I'm not familiar with the initializing jQuery syntax (whatever it's called.)

Comment: @strager - Oops you're right, thinking of a previous question, for this it'd be `$('<label />', { 'for': this.id, text: this.id })`, (`for` needs quotes since it's a keyword), you can give it a try here: http://jsfiddle.net/3JQp9/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the selector to the input elements within the #sg1 div:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sg1 input").each(function(){
        $(this).before(""+$(this).attr("id")+"");
    });
});
​</script>
<form id="sg1">
    <input name="member1" id="member1" value="jack" />
    <input name="member2" id="member2" value="carter" />
    <input name="member3" id="member3" value="jackson" />
    <input name="member4" id="member4" value="tielk" />    
</form>​
```

Comment: no :) it's before(), not prepend(), since prepend adds the content at the beginning of an element's content, while before adds it... well... before the element